# Getting id of dynamically created row

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a table of id productTable, I am adding rows using the following jquery code:

```
$('#productTable').html("");
for (var i = 0; i < result.count; i++) 
{
        $('#productTable').append('<tr id=' + result.productArray[i].productID + 'class="product"><td><a> '+result.productArray[i].productName+'</a></td></tr>');
}
```

and I'm attaching a handler to these rows using:

```
$("#productTable").on("click","tr",function(event){
                alert(this.id);
            });
```

but the ID that I'm getting is of the table whereas I want the id of the row that is being clicked.

Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$('#productTable').html("");
for (var i = 0; i < result.count; i++) 
{
    var obj = $('<tr id=' + result.productArray[i].productID + 'class="product"><td><a> '+result.productArray[i].productName+'</a></td></tr>');
    $(obj).click(function(event){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    $('#productTable').append(obj);
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this, what's the difference?

Comment: This may work (marginally), but the markup it creates is still invalid

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with what you're appending, it's not valid HTML

```
$('#productTable').append(
    '<tr id=' + result.productArray[i].productID + 'class="product">
         <td>
             <a> '+result.productArray[i].productName+'</a>
         </td>
     </tr>'
);
```

look very carefully, there's no quotes around the ID, and no space separating the ID and the class.
Basically you end up with

```
<tr id=idclass="product">
     <td>
         <a>text</a>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

The correct code would be

```
$('#productTable').append('<tr id="' + result.productArray[i].productID + '" class="product"><td><a> '+result.productArray[i].productName+'</a></td></tr>');
```

Comment: corrected the quotes issue, but the problem is still there

Comment: @MuhammadZaheer - Then we'll have to test it, and it seems to work for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/T4QRa/**....... ...... I already tested it of course, and the only issue I could find was the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

**[Bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)** Event when you creating element dynamically. This is another way to do what you want.

```
$('#productTable').html("");
for (var i = 0; i < result.count; i++) 
{
    $('#productTable').append('<tr id=" + result.productArray[i].productID + " class="product"><td><a> '+result.productArray[i].productName+'</a></td></tr>');
    $('#'+result.productArray[i].productID).bind('click',function(){
       //put your code here
    });
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bsLKP/1/)

Comment: Why would that work, but not the event delegation the OP uses?

Comment: @FelixKling this was only suggestion OP already accepted similar answer.